# Как сделать сохранение имени при перезагрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript

Вот такой небольшой пример чата на farebase есть -

```
<a href="https://codepen.io/iremlopsum/pen/ZWEdZj">пример на codepen</a>
```

Суть вопроса. Когда имя вводишь оно где-то сохраняется на время пока пользователь находится на странице, а при перезагрузки страницы введенное имя теряется и его нужно заново вводить. Как сделать чтобы имя сохранялось например в куках или ещё как и при перезагрузки страницы не пришлось заново вводить имя?

Answer (score 0):

У вас в вопросе ответ содержится - например в [куках](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie).
Можно еще в [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: я не могу это реализовать. Знаний нет

Comment: @stock на https://www.fl.ru/ вам что угодно реализуют, обращайтесь. Миллион исполнителей готовы вам помочь